# Combining doctests and `extern crate`

Tags: rust, rustdoc

In Rust 2018 I can use `extern self as crate_name` and then use fully-qualified syntax, for example

```rust
extern crate self as crate_name; //set our crate name
pub struct Member;
fn test() { 
    ::crate_name::Member; //use fully-qualified name
}
```

However I can't seem to make it work in a doctest:

````rust
/// ```
/// extern crate self as crate_name; //set the crate name
/// pub struct Member;
/// fn test() { 
/// ::crate_name::Member; //use fully-qualified name
/// }
/// ```
fn example() { }
````

> error[E0425]: cannot find value `Member` in module `crate_name`

I should mention that I am actually doctesting a procmacro.  That is, a) the test needs to contain fully-qualified syntax, since the procmacro expands to that, b) I need to adjust the test prelude so that the expansion will compile.  Basically the doctest should mock the types/paths so the procmacro can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [as described here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html#pre-processing-examples) if `fn main()` doesn't appear in the doctest, rustdoc will wrap the test inside a `main`, so the mocked types are actually declared inside this function..

Including a `main` function in the test opts out of this and allows control of where the types are declared

````rust
/// ```
/// extern crate self as crate_name; //pretend we're some crate
/// pub struct Member;
/// fn main() { ::crate_name::Member; //demo fully-qualified name
/// }
/// ```
fn example() { }
````